# How do i print the the first initial of a string and the last word of a string?

Tags: java

How do I print only the first letter of the first word and the whole word of the last? for example,
I will request username input like "Enter your first and last name" and then if I type my name like "Peter Griffin", I want to print only "P and Griffin". I hope this question make sense. Please, help. I'm a complete beginner as you can tell.
Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    String fname=scan.next();
}
```

Comment: Have a look through the Javadoc of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), there are quite a few helpful methods for you to find in there.

Comment: input.charAt(0) +" "+ input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1); = P Griffin

Answer (score 0):

The String methods *trim*, *substring*, *indexof*, *lastindexof*, and maybe *split* should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work (typed directly here, so syntax errors might be there)

```
  String fname=scan.nextLine(); // or however you would read whole line
  String parts=fname.split(" ");
  System.out.printf("%s %s",parts[0].substring(0,1),parts[parts.length-1]);
```

What you have to do next:

1. Check if there actually at least 2 elements in `parts` array
2. Check if first element is actually at least 1 char (no empty parts)
3. Check if there is actually line to read
4. Do your next homework yourself, otherwise you will not anything

Comment: Changed to next line

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to watch subString(1, x) and indexOf(" ") to cut from index 1 to first space.

or here a other exemple, dealing with lower and multi name :

```
    String s = "peter griffin foobar";

    String[] splitted = s.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

    results.append(String.valueOf(splitted[0].charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + " ");
    for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        results.append(splitted[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + splitted[i].substring(1)+" ");
    }
    System.out.println(results.toString());
```